# What does 上 without a particle means?

Tags: particles, particle-に, sentence

[image]

幽霊事件はその特異性上どうしても捜査が後手に回ってしまう

My understanding of the sentence is that she's saying that due to the 特異性 nature of the case in the end the investigation falls behind/stalls 後手に回ってしまう.

However I'm curios on how 上 by itself is acting here. I would assume it's either 上に or　上で, however the particle is entirely omitted so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

When used as a suffix, it is read 上{じょう} an it turns the preceding word into a のadjective or an adverb. Just as Xの上{うえ}で, it means "in terms of X"([see this for reference](https://hedgehog-japanese.com/grammar/jlpt-n2/jou/)).

For example:

> 歴史 History ->  歴史上 "In terms of history", i.e. "Historical, Historic"

> 形式　Form, format, style -> 形式上 "In terms of format", i.e "Ceremonial"

> 特異性　singularity, peculiarity -> 特異性 "In terms of peculiarity".

Comment: This is mostly correct, but note that this construction is not really limited to meaning "in terms of" - it can also just mean "due to" when it relates to the reasons for something, as in the OP's question. Your linked reference actually gives quite a few examples like this.